# accessing values incorrectly from list in python

Tags: python, list, pyparsing

I have two example files.

```
myheader.h

#define MACRO1 42
#define lang_init ()  c_init()
#define min(X, Y)  ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))
```

and pyparser.py

```
from pyparsing import *
# define the structure of a macro definition (the empty term is used 
# to advance to the next non-whitespace character)
macroDef = "#define" + Word(alphas+"_",alphanums+"_").setResultsName("macro") + \
            empty + restOfLine.setResultsName("value")
with open('myheader.h', 'r') as f:
    res = macroDef.scanString(f.read())
    res = list(res)
    print(res[0])
    print(res[1])
    print(res[2])
```

the output is

`((['#define', 'MACRO1', '42'], {'macro': ['MACRO1'], 'value': ['42']}), 0, 17) ((['#define', 'lang_init', '()  c_init()'], {'macro': ['lang_init'], 'value': ['()  c_init()']}), 18, 48) ((['#define', 'min', '(X, Y)  ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))'], {'macro': ['min'], 'value': ['(X, Y)  ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))']}), 49, 91)`

I thought print(res[0]) would print "#define", print print(res[1]) would print 'MACRO1' and so on. I'm not that familiar with Python, but I'm assuming res is not an array correct? How does indexing works in this case? Thanks

Comment: What output do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Question, what is the value of len(res).

In python when you have a list inside of a list you can use a second indexer to access the elements inside of it. So for example if the first element res[0] was a list, you could do res[0][0] to get '#define'.

However, your output that you have shown is in a different format than typical nested list syntax, so doing res[0][0] might not work (because it might not be the right type of object).

This is what a nested list is supposed to look like:
[[0, 1], [1, 2, 100], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]

Your output looks like its in json formatting, but without knowing the type of data object it is for sure I can't be certain. If it is json, you might be able to do json.loads(res) and then parse it that way.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-json-how-to-convert-a-string-to-json/

Comment: I did len(res) and it output 3

Comment: so I did res[0][0][0]) and it printed #define, then res[0][0][1]) and it printed MACRO1, then res[0][0][2]) and it printed 42.  res[1][0][0]) would print the next #define, res[1][0][1]) prints  lang_init () and so on. I think this is what I wanted. So again this is not a conventional array?

Comment: Happy it worked for you. Python does not have arrays, it has lists. It is not a conventional list because based on what you have told me it is a super nested list that is going at least 3 levels deep.

Answer (score -1):

Part of your confusion stems from a misunderstanding of what you get back from scanString. scanString (which is a legacy compatibility name for the new method scan_string) is actually a generator, which yields a tuple for each found match. The tuple contains:

- the ParseResults returned from matching some text to the scan expression
- the starting position of where the text was found
- the ending position of where the text was found

If you don't want the position values, use search_string instead, which will just return a list of the ParseResults for each match.

Check out the online docs for more details on how to work with scan_string, search_string, ParserElements, and ParseResults.
https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/